# CSS tag fa fa- own use possible?

Tags: html, css, class

Is it possible to use the css class fa fa- for own images. Like fa fa-img ? I want to include my own image into the fa tag.

[image]

Comment: can you be more specific? can you add a link to that page?

Comment: you can call your class whatever you like

Comment: @Roysh It's from [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome_icons_intro.asp)

Comment: You seems HTML CSS beginner, `fa fa` isn't tag, it's a class which is using fonts.

Comment: What you have here is a character/font which looks like a car. you can give it any size you want with css

Comment: Im using a ready template for a single page website. I want to change the icons which are included with the class  .fa fa-tree for example. I want to replace it with my own image. But if I include my own image to wont be shown for some reasons. Thats why I m askin if  I can include my image into .fa fa-img or so ?

Comment: you want to create your own image as a font?
you should have your image on an svg format and then convert to a font.
you can use glyphter - https://glyphter.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, Ex: FB

This will replace the font with your custom image.

```
.fa-facebook{
    content: '';
    background:url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-VPr8buUo47w/VjMsRPIzr-I/AAAAAAAAAL4/AYBtvlNCQiw/s64-Ic42/clouds_social_media_icons_set_64x64_0000_facebook.png");
    width:64px;
    height:64px;  
    display:inline-block;
}
```

or with

```
.fa-facebook::before{content:url("")}
```

Comment: Use custom class, otherwise this will override `font-awesome`'s CSS

Comment: I solved it.  In my html page I added the image into <i>-tag. Now my icons are showing.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you will just need to set the CSS rule applicable for that case:

```
.your-class {
    background-image: url(/your/path/to/your/image.png);
}
```

If the rule is not specific-enough, then you can make it more specific or mark it as `important`, like:

```
.your-class {
    background-image: url(/your/path/to/your/image.png) !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If You want edit Font Awesome (or include your own icons)?

You can use [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/). Browse to the library page and use [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/), you can augment FontAwesome's libary with your custom icons in SVG.

Otherwise Can you please add more specific ?